# ORA-00936: missing expression oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, expression, ora-00936

I have this query

```
SELECT DAL_ROWNOTABLE.DAL_ID FROM 
(
    SELECT ticket.id AS "DAL_ID",  ROWNUMBER ( Order By ticket.id  )  AS "DAL_ROWNUMBER" 
    FROM ticket_table ticket 
    WHERE ( ticket.type = N'I' ) 
    AND 
    ( 
        ticket.tenant IS NULL OR ticket.tenant IN 
        (
            SELECT  * FROM 
            ( 
                SELECT tenant_group_member.tenant_id 
                FROM tenant_group_member 
                WHERE tenant_group_member.tenant_group = HEXTORAW('30B0716FEB5F4E4BB82A7B7AA3A1A42C') 
                ORDER BY ticket.id 
            ) 
         ) 
     )
) DAL_ROWNOTABLE 
WHERE DAL_ROWNOTABLE.DAL_ROWNUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 21
```

What is the problem with the allow query that is throwing ORA-00936 missing expression? anyone? Any help will be appreciated...Error thrown at column:80 which is at the beginning of first order by:

Comment: More readable though @wildplasser

Comment: The `ORDER BY` in the subquery is completely meaningless, and so is the subquerey surronding it.

Comment: Thanks wildplasser, the query modification suggested by Gordon is working...I will check that out further......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query can be much simplified.  It has things like extra layers of subqueries and an unnecessary `order by` in an `in` subquery.  What you want to do with `rownumber` you can do with just `rownum`:

```
SELECT DAL_ROWNOTABLE.DAL_ID
FROM (SELECT ticket.id AS "DAL_ID" 
      FROM ticket_table ticket 
      WHERE (ticket.type = N'I' ) AND 
            (ticket.tenant IS NULL OR
             ticket.tenant IN (SELECT tgm.tenant_id 
                               FROM tenant_group_member tgm
                               WHERE tgm.tenant_group = HEXTORAW('30B0716FEB5F4E4BB82A7B7AA3A1A42C') 
                              ) 
            )
      ORDER BY ticket.id
     ) DAL_ROWNOTABLE 
WHERE rownum <= 21;
```

Comment: Seems like it did the trick...Thanks to Gordon :) and other too...I will test this out further....

Answer (score 2):

ORA-00936 usually indicates a syntax error.

`ROWNUMBER` is not an Oracle function.  Unless you have a user-defined function of that name I suspect the function you're looking for is [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/olap.112/e23381/olap_functions022.htm#OLAXS333).